# Facebook Integration Android: onCompleted(GraphJSONObjectCallback) block not executing

Tags: android, android-facebook

I am trying to build an app which fetches all photos from facebook profile and this code is in the UserProfileActivity. But the intent which starts this activity is inside GraphRequest onCompleted block. This block is never getting executed as I saw while debugging. I tried a lot to understand it and saw various posts and everywhere the code is like this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FacebookCallback<LoginResult>{
private LoginButton buttonLoginFacebook;
private TextView textViewMessage;
private CallbackManager callbackManager;

private String TAG = "MainActivity";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    buttonLoginFacebook = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.buttonLoginFacebook);
    buttonLoginFacebook.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile, user_photos, user_posts"));
    textViewMessage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewMessage);

    buttonLoginFacebook.registerCallback(callbackManager,this);
}

@Override
public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(),
            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
            Log.e(TAG,object.toString());
            Log.e(TAG,response.toString());
            try{
                String userId = object.getString("id");
                URL profilePicture = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + userId + "/picture?width=500&height=500");
                String fullName="";
                if(object.has("first_name"))
                    fullName += object.getString("first_name");
                if(object.has("last_name"))
                    fullName += " " + object.getString("last_name");

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,UserProfileActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("name",fullName);
                intent.putExtra("imageUrl",profilePicture.toString());
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "id, first_name, last_name");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
}

@Override
public void onCancel() {
    textViewMessage.setText("Login attempt cancelled");
}

@Override
public void onError(FacebookException error) {
    textViewMessage.setText("Login attempt failed");
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
}
```

The code is never getting inside the onCompleted block. Thus the intent for UserProfileActivity is never getting executed. I am a little new to Facebook Sdk so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it calling onError or onCancel.?

Comment: It is inside onSuccess(). The code inside newMeRequest is not executing

Answer (score 0):

its working for me

```
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult success) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.d("facebookLogin", "successful"
                            + success.getRecentlyGrantedPermissions()
                            .toString() + " " + success.toString());

                    AccessToken token = success.getAccessToken();

                    if (token == null) {
                        Log.e("FBaccessToken", "null");
                    } else {
                        Log.d("FBAccesstoken", token.toString());
                        getFBMeData(token);
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                    if (e instanceof FacebookException) {
                        if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
                            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                        }

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.d("facebookLogin", "canceled by user");

                }
            });

}

public void getFBMeData(AccessToken atoken) {
    Profile.fetchProfileForCurrentAccessToken();
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,
                                        GraphResponse response) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (object != null) {
                        Log.d("FBGraphJSONObject", object.toString());

                        if(Profile.getCurrentProfile()!=null) {
                            FBdata.put("fbid", Profile.getCurrentProfile()
                                    .getId());
                            FBdata.put("fname", Profile.getCurrentProfile()
                                    .getFirstName());
                            FBdata.put("lname", Profile.getCurrentProfile()
                                    .getLastName());
                            String gender = object.optString("gender");
                            String dob = object.optString("birthday");
                            String locationName = "";
                            JSONObject location = object
                                    .optJSONObject("location");
                            if (location != null) {
                                locationName = location.optString("name");
                            }
                            String pictureUrl = "", email = "";
                            JSONObject picture = object
                                    .optJSONObject("picture");
                            JSONObject data = picture.optJSONObject("data");
                            try {
                                email = URLDecoder.decode(
                                        object.optString("email"), "UTF-8");
                                if (picture != null) {
                                    pictureUrl = URLDecoder.decode(
                                            data.optString("url"), "UTF-8");
                                }
                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            FBdata.put("photo", pictureUrl);
                            FBdata.put("address", locationName);
                            FBdata.put("dob", dob);
                            FBdata.put("gender", gender);
                            FBdata.put("email", email);
                    }
                }
            });
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("fields", "gender,email,birthday,location,picture");
    request.setParameters(params);
    request.executeAsync();

}
```

Comment: Thank you but the problem is still the same. My code is not getting inside the onCompleted block. What is the probable cause if you can tell for this.

Comment: have u checked the  app id and the keyhash?

Comment: Yes. I getting logged into facebook

Comment: I mean I'm already getting logged in but the block is not getting executed to start the new activity :O

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, The Issue was android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException,So Make Sure You Call Network Request in a Separate Thread.